# embedding_vectors = get_weight_matrix(w2v_model)

Tags: python

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-184-6ab4a6968e06> in <module>()
----> 1 embedding_vectors = get_weight_matrix(w2v_model)

3 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/gensim/models/keyedvectors.py in word_vec(self, word, use_norm)
    450             return result
    451         else:
--> 452             raise KeyError("word '%s' not in vocabulary" % word)
    453 
    454     def get_vector(self, word):
```

Comment: KeyError: "word 'bengal' not in vocabulary" why its giving me error??

Comment: Without seeing your code, we can tell you nothing.  Your model evidently  tried to look up the word "bengal", and it wasn't present.

Comment: So where on earth is the code that causes this error? :D

Comment: I guess if you are using w2v (something like `gensim` or similar libraries), you sould first check if `word in w2v_model` and then do sth like `w2v_model[word]`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Why do you believe the word "bengal" should be in the vocabulary?